# Type safety with similar enums

Tags: java, enums, api-design, conventions, type-safety

Say I have the methods:

```
void foo(String color) { /* should only allow "RED", "ORANGE" */ }
void bar(String color) { /* should only allow "RED", "ORANGE", "YELLOW" */ } 
void baz(String color) { /* should only allow "RED", "ORANGE", "YELLOW", "GREEN" */ }
```

If we accept type String, there is no type safety and it would not be recommended since we know what keys are valid at compile time.

Now I could create separate enums for these methods to ensure type safety:

```
enum Color1 { RED, ORANGE; }
enum Color2 { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW; }
enum Color3 { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN; }
void foo(Color1 color) { /* only allows one of [RED, ORANGE] */ }
void bar(Color2 color) { /* only allows one of [RED, ORANGE, YELLOW] */ }
void baz(Color3 color) { /* only allows one of [RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN] */ }
```

or reduce type safety with just use one enum and throw an appropriate exception:

```
enum Color { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN; }
void foo(Color color) { /* throws if not in [RED, ORANGE] */ }
void bar(Color color) { /* throws if not in [RED, ORANGE, YELLOW] */ }
void baz(Color color) {}
```

I want to follow the principle of least astonishment so giving exceptions feels wrong when we know what is valid at compile time but, at the same time, having many enums that are very similar and are essentially extensions of each other feels equally as wrong.

What is preferable in this case?

Comment: There's no correct answer to this question, unfortunately.  Just do whatever you prefer!

Comment: Why are enums so special? The same problem applies when you have a method that only takes positive numbers. Or odd numbers. Or Strings of length 5. The Java type system (and the type system of most current widely used languages) is not designed for that kind of fine-grained typing (which has a lot of interesting theoretical-mathematical implications that most people are not prepared to handle)